# Disable tracking of specific fields of Custom Object from Apex?

Tags: apex, custom-object

We released a package with some of the fields in our custom objects unintentionally having "track field history" enabled.

I'm wondering if there's a way from our Install script of our next build (or a patch release) to programmatically disable that settings.  We've changed the object definition, and that covers fresh installs, but having it set to "false" doesn't alter the existing settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately these are not not upgradable. The following help topics are invaluable when deteming what can and cannot be edited by your users and thus not upgradable after initial install.

- [Components Automatically Added to Packages](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_components_auto_added.htm)
- [Available Components](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_packageable_components.htm)
- [Editing Components and Attributes After Installation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_component_attributes.htm)

'Track Field History' is described in the 'Subscriber and Developer Editable' column which is described as...

> The subscriber and developer can edit the component attributes in this column. However, they’re not upgradeable; only new subscribers receive the latest changes.

**Post Install Script** Post install scripts have to be written in Apex and unfortuantly there is no direct API for updating these settings from this environment. You can utilse the [Salesforce Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/), using the '[update](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_update.htm)' operation with the [CustomField](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customfield.htm) type to toggle the trackHistory field. While this is possible to call out to this API from [Apex](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) (see here for an [example](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L111) of a field update), you would need to have had your subscriber org configure the appropriate [Remote Site setting](http://eu2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/configuring_remoteproxy.htm) to enable it.

**Post Install Email / Tool.** The best I think you can do is have your Install Script email the person doing the install to send them details in an email of the steps to perform manually. Or if you want to pursue a tool based on the Metadata API, direct them to a VF page in your package the performs the steps for them. Thats definitly possible, though still needs the Remote Site setting defined before such a tool can be used.

Comment: Andrew you are becoming the Jon Skeet of SFSE :)

Comment: Just looked him up, wow! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, metadata isn't something you can update with Apex Code. You'll have to instruct your clients to manually disable this tracking.