# Can the tooling API turn off field tracking history?

Tags: tooling-api, field-history

Can the tooling API turn off/on field tracking history? Seeing as we can't [delete history record](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000JCiz) I want to be able to turn it off before a process runs to prevent history records being created.

The tooling API is new to me and I can see there is the [IsFieldHistoryTracked for EntityDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) -  - I just can't figure out if it's possible to edit via the tooling API.

Background:
Basically we need to be able to clear address data on sandbox creation - however the original remains in the associated history records.

Comment: You could use a metadata api call instead, as detailed in this [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13407/10382).

Comment: The linked question works with CustomField via the Metadata API. You can get to the same record in the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm). It looks like the trackFeedHistory is accessible through the Metadata field.

Comment: Any reason I should use one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments that helped me look at the right place...

With the help of [Andrew Fawcett's Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) and in particular the demo metadatadeply.vfp I can confirm that the metadata API can turn off/on field history for an object.

I edited the zip file to update the Account object and to include:

```
<enableHistory>true</enableHistory>
```

Salesforce maintains what fields have field tracking enabled when it is turned off at the object level, so turning it on/off at the object level is all I need.